# Выборка из двух таблиц MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы `table_firm и table_update`. Необходимо выбрать фирмы из таблицы `table_firm` по их последней активности содержащейся в таблице/поле `table_update.dateupdate`.
Структуры таблиц:

```
table_firm (id, name_firm) 
table_update (id, id_firm, dateupdate)
```

где,

```
table_firm.id = table_update.id_firm
```

dateupdate содержит дату в виде 20120212

В итоге нужно вывести список фирм из таблицы `table_firm` так чтобы сначала шли фирмы с нибольшим числом в поле dateupdate таблицы `table_update`.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде так:

```
SELECT tr.*, tu.* FROM `table_update` tu
JOIN LEFT `table_firm` tr ON tr.id = tu.id_firm
ORDER BY tu.dateupdate DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

LIMIT 0,10 - выбирает 10 последних строк... можно эту запись не добавлятьв запрос, тогда выдаст всю таблицу...

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.name_firm 
   from table_firm a join
       (select id_firm, max(dateupdate) as upd 
            from table_update group by id_firm) b
   where a.id = b.id_firm
   order by b.upd desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tf.name_firm
  FROM table_firm tf, table_update tu
 WHERE tf.id = tu.id_firm
ORDER BY tu.date_update DESC
```

а поле date_update какого типа?)

Comment: поле dateupdate bigint

Comment: нафига дату хранить так?)
в моем скрипте можно еще distinct добавить.